# Joining two or more tables

Tags: sql

I have written some code to merge two tables together. The values that are displayed are null.

```
+----------+--------------+-----------------------------------------------+-------------+----------+----------+------+----------+
| Movie_ID | Release_year | Movie_Title                                   | Duration    | Genre_ID | Actor_ID | Role | Movie_ID |
+----------+--------------+-----------------------------------------------+-------------+----------+----------+------+----------+
| 10001    | 1997         | Titantic                                      | 190 minutes | 40001    | NULL     | NULL | NULL     |
| 10002    | 1998         | Shakesphere in Love                           | 123 minutes | 40002    | NULL     | NULL | NULL     |
| 10003    | 1999         | American Beauty                               | 122 minutes | 40003    | NULL     | NULL | NULL     |
| 10004    | 2000         | Gladiator                                     | 155 minutes | 40004    | NULL     | NULL | NULL     |
| 10005    | 2001         | A beautiful Mind                              | 135 minutes | 40004    | NULL     | NULL | NULL     |
| 10006    | 2002         | Chicago                                       | 113 minutes | 40005    | NULL     | NULL | NULL     |
| 10007    | 2003         | The Lord of the Rings: The return of the King | 201 minutes | 40006    | NULL     | NULL | NULL     |
| 10008    | 2004         | Million Dollar Baby                           | 132 minutes | 40007    | NULL     | NULL | NULL     |
| 10009    | 2005         | Crash                                         | 112 minutes | 40008    | NULL     | NULL | NULL     |
| 10010    | 2006         | The Departed                                  | 151 minutes | 40009    | NULL     | NULL | NULL     |
| 10011    | 2007         | No Country for Old Men                        | 122 minutes | 40009    | NULL     | NULL | NULL     |
| 10012    | 2008         | Slumdog Millionaire                           | 120 minutes | 40008    | NULL     | NULL | NULL     |
| 10013    | 2009         | The Hurt Locker                               | 131 minutes | 40009    | NULL     | NULL | NULL     |
| 10014    | 2010         | The King\s speech                             | 118 minutes | 40010    | NULL     | NULL | NULL     |
| 10015    | 2011         | The Artist                                    | 100 minutes | 40011    | NULL     | NULL | NULL     |
| 10016    | 2012         | Argo                                          | 120 minutes | 40012    | NULL     | NULL | NULL     |
| 10017    | 2013         | 12 Years a Slave                              | 134 minutes | 40004    | NULL     | NULL | NULL     |
| 10018    | 2014         | Birdman or The Unexpected Virtue of Ignorance | 119 minutes | 40003    | NULL     | NULL | NULL     |
| 10019    | 2015         | Spotlight                                     | 129 minutes | 40008    | NULL     | NULL | NULL     |
| 10020    | 2016         | Moonlight                                     | 111 minutes | 40013    | NULL     | NULL | NULL     |
| 10021    | 2017         | The Shape of Water                            | 123 minutes | 40012    | NULL     | NULL | NULL     |
| 10022    | 2018         | Green Book                                    | 130 minutes | 40011    | NULL     | NULL | NULL     |
+----------+--------------+-----------------------------------------------+-------------+----------+----------+------+----------+
```

```
SELECT *
FROM databaseoscars.movie a
LEFT JOIN  databaseoscars.`movie cast` b ON a.Movie_ID = b.Actor_ID;
```

I expected the output to be all data is displayed on one table.

Comment: individually use aliases for asterisks such as `a.*,b.*`. Perhaps you need `FULL OUTER JOIN`. Btw, join condition seems skew : Movie_ID vs. Actor_ID

Comment: You should tag SQL questions always with the DBMS you are using. From the non-standard name delimiters I conclude it's MySQL or MariaDB? Which and which version? BTW: I'd avoid names that make quoting necessary. You could call the table `movie_cast` and thus get rid of the quotes. And you should use mnemonic aliases like m for movie, rather than generic names like a,b, c. Aliases shall enhance, not decrease a query's readability.

Comment: I tried to remove the quote marks but I get an error on the aliases.

Comment: That is because `movie cast` are two words. You would have to rename the table from `movie cast` to `movie_cast`. This was my advice.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is here: `a.Movie_ID = b.Actor_ID`. A movie will never be an actor. Use your movie cast table's movie ID instead:

```
SELECT * 
FROM databaseoscars.movie m
LEFT JOIN databaseoscars.`movie cast` mc ON mc.movie_id = m.movie_id;
```

In MySQL and MariaDB, you could also use the `USING` clause:

```
SELECT * 
FROM databaseoscars.movie m
LEFT JOIN databaseoscars.`movie cast` mc USING (movie_id);
```

Comment: @KabirdevRamana . . . If this answers your question and you think it is the best answer, you should accept it.

Comment: The answer helps and it works as expected. Thank you